# clear_contents() in xlwings is not clearing chart

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am trying to clear a worksheet in Excel so that I can place a new Excel chart in the worksheet when I click a macro button.

I've tried clear(), clear_contents(), and chart.delete() which don't work the way I want it to.

```
import xlwings as xw

def main():
   wb = xw.Book.caller()
   Sheet = wb.sheets('Sheet')
   Sheet.range('A1:P200').clear()
   Sheet.range('A1').value = [['Foo1', 'Foo2'], [1, 2]]
   chart = Sheet.charts.add(left=410, top=0, width=355, height=211)
   chart.set_source_data(Sheet.range('A1').expand())
```

Edit:
I just added another button to clear charts using just VBA. But let me know if there's a Python solution.

Comment: Delete the sheet and then create a new sheet with the same name.

Comment: is there a way through code rather than deleting the sheet?

Comment: @hengjuice Delete the sheet and recreate using xlwings code, I didn't mean do it manually.